# Sublime Text 3: Change comment language

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Suddenly, using the comment shortcut Ctrl+/ to comment out a line has stopped commenting in the proper language. I code in php so an inline comment should look like this:

```
// Commented out
```

Now, my comments look like this:

```
{{-- Commented out --}}
```

The file type is set to php. No clue what happened. How can I reset this?

Another interesting fact: only php is messed up. Html, css, and javascript all use the correct comment type.

Comment: This seems like you're working on a template file like `.twig.php`. Is it the case ?

Comment: Nope. Just a standard php file. I tried several files in several projects and they are all using the wrong comment style.

Comment: Try to show the commands palette `ctrl+shift+P` and type `Toggle Comment` then `Enter`

Comment: Same broken comments :(

Comment: Weird, what does `ctrl+shift+alt+P` shows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, I solved disabling laravel blade syntax highlighter plugin. Give it a try.

Comment: That was it. Heres the issue on github: https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/issues/123 It has now been resolved so a re-install fixed the problem. Thanks!